# Type 'PFFacebookUtils' has no member 'session' on swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.0, pffacebookutils

I am trying integrate Facebook login using Parse, but the following code: `var FBSession = PFFacebookUtils.session` gives the error

> Type "PFFacebookUtils" has no member "session"

I am using the latest Parse SDK and Facebook SDKs, is "session" method deprecated or what? 
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The latest API for PFFacebookUtils](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html) doesn't show a `session` member, although [older documentation does show it](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ParseFacebookUtils/1.7.2/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html) (and a dramatically different set of API's)

And ultimately what happened was that Parse replaced `FBSession` with `FBSDKLoginManager`, [as described in this changelog from 3.x to 4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x).  They do recommend reading the ["Upgrade the iOS SDK from 3.x to 4.x document"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x).

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer necessary to explicitly close a session in ParseFacebookUtilsV4.